# Input type number not working as expected, can not enter numbers 1, 2, 3

Tags: html, reactjs, input

I have a input box in React project which needs to accept all numbers (eg: 0 - 9 ). But accepting only 4 - 9.

```
<input 
    type="number" 
    onChange={handleChangePageNumber}  
    min={1} 
    max={100} 
/>
```

How can i fix this issue and what is the reason for this issue?

Comment: What does `handleChangePageNumber` do?

Comment: @Justinas its just a function which reads the entered value. It will  not work even If I am removing the onChange function

Comment: Ensure there is no other events that listens for this field and updates values

Comment: That snippet works fine. If it doesn't there is something else you don't show us. But be aware, that `min` and `max` of an input won't prevent from typing an out of range value ...